# Actual residential address does not match with the one in my passport

Tags: esta

I applied for the ESTA a couple weeks ago and it got accepted, but I noticed I have put my actual residential address in the form which is different from the one in my passport, can I get denied the entry because of that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I applied for the ESTA a couple weeks ago and it got accepted, but I noticed I have put my actual residential address in the form which is different from the one in my passport

Passports are valid for sometimes 10 years, everyone can't be expected to stay at the same place for 10 years, what is important are the facts now.

You won't be denied on that point at all

As an added, most countries will not require you to renew your passport on a change of address basis alone, including the US

> No, you don’t need to update your current passport with your new address

Due to production delays, France even stopped allowing those kinds of applications (for change of address) for a little while

Comment: My UK passports have never shown my residential address, neither before or after being a member of the European Union.

Comment: Neither has my Dutch passport.